# I have a wireless Canon P560 and my computer can't find it

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, printer

The printer is wireless and I haven't connected it via USB. I set the configurations for the Wi-Fi access point in the printer and it connected to my Wi-Fi. I have AT&T as the service provider and the 2Wire router. When I access the router in the browser I see that the printer is connected but when I run the software to detect the printer the computer can't find it. I have a Mac with Snow Leopard. I tried to detect the printer with another device and it can't find it. Is there a port that needs to be open for wireless printers? Because I tried putting the routers firewall settings for the device to its lowest and the computer still can't find it. Let me know. Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried inserting the IP address instead of using Bonjour to detect your printer (which I'm assuming you're doing)?

Check for the IP address in your router's configuration pages. Or it might show on your printer's screen?

Comment: There's an IP tab in the Print & Fax System Preferences panel for you to enter the IP address. (System Preference->Print & Fax->+ icon->click on IP tab)

Snow Leopard has lots of printer drivers in it by default. If it doesn't it'll Software Update to get the printer drivers package from Apple.